# Getting error Notice: Undefined index: in PHP using isset and form

Tags: php, isset

### EDIT:

Since my question was marked as duplicate, I have to give more explanation about my question. I has done searching and reading for a days. All the answer suggest to using `isset` which I'm already using it. But, cause of I'm lack of knowledge, I can't figure it out about the real cause of my problem. Then I hoping that I can get some help, skills, and more knowledge here.

I made a page that sending data using form into 7 column in stockout table on DB. When I do checking the data on DB, only 5 column were getting the data while for column balance and totalout I'm getting 0 as value. Then I try debugging by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.

Here are the errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: balance in C:\xampp\unixa\module\stock\stockout.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: totalout in C:\xampp\unixa\module\stock\stockout.php on line 30
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $Conn = ConnDB();
    // $Conn->debug=true;

    $id = htmlentities($_POST['id'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $sql = "SELECT
                    inventories.id,
                    inventories.categories,
                    brands.`name` AS brandname,
                    inventories.model,
                    inventories.qty,
                    inventories.datein,
                    inventories.invoice,
                    inventories.price
                    FROM inventories
                    INNER JOIN brands ON brands.id = inventories.brand_id
                    WHERE
                    inventories.id = '$id'";

    $rs = $Conn->execute($sql);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $machineid = htmlentities($_POST['machineid'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $qty = htmlentities($_POST['qty'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $balance = htmlentities($_POST['balance'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $totalout = htmlentities($_POST['totalout'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $dateout = htmlentities($_POST['dateout'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $id = htmlentities($_POST['id'], ENT_QUOTES);

        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO stockout (inventorie_id, machines_id, qty, balance, totalout, dateout)
                        VALUES ('$id', '$machineid', '$qty', '$balance', '$totalout', '$dateout')";
        $rs3 = $Conn->execute($sql3);

        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">
                        <a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"close\">×</a>
                        <strong>Add stock out successfully</strong>
                </div>";
    }   
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });

    function calculateTotal() {

        var totalAmt = document.stockout.qty.value;
        totalR = eval(totalAmt * document.inventories.price.value);

        document.getElementById('totalout').value = totalR;

        };
</script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3">   
    <h4>Stock Out</h4>
<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['categories'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="brand">Brand:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['brandname'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="model">Model:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['model'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="datein">Date In:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['datein'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="invoiceno">Invoice No:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['invoice'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="qty">Quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['qty'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <form name="inventories" action="" id="inventories" >
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Price per Unit (RM):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" onclick="calculateTotal()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" value="<?php echo $rs->fields['price'] ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>

</div>

</form>
<form data-toggle="validator" method="post" action="" name="stockout" action="" id="stockout">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="machineid"><font color="red"></font> Machine ID:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="machineid" name="machineid" />
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <?php
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM machines ORDER BY id";
                    $rs2 = $Conn->execute($sql2);
                    while(!$rs2->EOF){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rs2->fields['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rs2->fields['id'] ?></option>
                <?php
                    $rs2->moveNext(); }
                ?>                  
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="qty"><font color="red">*</font> Quantity Out:</label>
            <input type="text" name="qty" class="form-control" onchange="calculateTotal()" onclick="calculateTotal()" id="qty" name="qty" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="balance">Balance:</label>
            <?php 
                $stockqty = $rs->fields['id'];
                $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(qty) AS total FROM stockout WHERE inventorie_id='$stockqty'";
                $rs2 = $Conn->execute($sql2);

            ?>          
            <input type="text" name="balance" class="form-control" id="balance" placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['qty'] - $rs2->fields['total']; ?>" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="totalout">Amount (RM):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalout" name="totalout" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="dateout"><font color="red">*</font> Date Out:</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="color:black">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id="dateout" name="dateout" required />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $rs->fields['id'] ?>"/>
</div>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
</form>
</div>
```

I'm beginner, and most of my code I got from internet. Hopes you guys can help me to fix in declare the variables. Thanks.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard, right now this page I'll use in local network only. I'm planning to secure my page in future.

Comment: If you don't have time to do it properly (**safely**) the first time, you won't find that time later neither. Or, when you do, it's just that you'll have to, because some ill-intended one stepped in. Too late mate, all data's gone...

Comment: Gladly I found the cause of the error. It's just disable code at line `<input type="text" name="balance" class="form-control" id="balance" placeholder="<?php echo $rs->fields['qty'] - $rs2->fields['total']; ?>" disabled />` and `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalout" name="totalout" disabled />`. I change it into `readonly="true"` and it's done, my declaration error is gone. Thanks all for the tips and knowledge. I'll take your advice @OldPadawan to implement security on my page asap. Thanks again.